# azure documentdb culture while sorting

Tags: azure-cosmosdb

I have doucuments(json) in English and in French stores in my documentdb collection.

While doing query using sort descending by title ( a property of my document), the result seem to be wrong.

Instead of beginning by Z-A , its started by special character such as 'Ö', 'é', 'Á' and then go to Z-A.

Answer (score 1):

DocumentDB uses [UTF-8 strings](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8) per JSON standard. So sort by strings also follows UTF-8 order, i.e. this is the expected behavior.

For a different sort order, you have to store a canonicalized version of the string, then use it for sorting. For example, for case-insensitive sort, you'd store the lower case representation of the string as a separate property. If you want accents to be ignored (é = "e"), then you'd store a mapping of the string without accents.

Comment: Having to duplicate your document information just for sorting purposes simply does not feel right to me.